# Bootstrap alert not working when clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, alert

Facing a very silly issue. I am showing alert message on a button click. It works perfectly at first click but then it is not working on next clicks,

Here is my code : http://jsfiddle.net/nre6fbm5/

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Dismissal Alert Messages</h2>
    <button>Send Message</button>
    <div class="alert alert-danger fade alert-conatiner">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> Error! Can not proceed.
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $(".alert").delay(1000).addClass("in").fadeOut(4000);
  })
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Downvoter, please write the reason in comment to downvote. Please don't spoil the community without any reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One string solution:

```
$(".alert").delay(1000).addClass("in").toggle(true).fadeOut(4000);
```

**Edit:**
The problem why it worked only once was that `display: none` was added by `fadeout` function. `.toggle(true)` will set display property to block just before the fadeout fires. See more about this:

[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

[.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

Working code here : http://jsfiddle.net/hxxjgh63/

Comment: Thats beautiful. Could you please add a bit explanation so that I can upvote and accept it. It will be helpful for others also

Comment: this is pretty neat and simple. =)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help, you have to remove class "in".

The second thing: style="display:none" auto added in ".alert" after fading out. Set this to empty

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $(".alert").delay(1000).addClass("in").fadeOut(4000);
    setTimeout(function(){      
        $(".alert").removeClass("in").css('display','');
    },5500);
  })
});
```

[Your demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nre6fbm5/31/)

Answer (score 1):

`in` class not enough to show `alert` next time because it set `display: none`, you need to set `fadeIn` as you set `fadeOut`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $(".alert").fadeIn().addClass('in').delay(4000).promise().done(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("in").fadeOut();
    });
  })
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nre6fbm5/89/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass a callback on your `fadeOut` effect after you set the `duration`

> [`.fadeOut( [duration ] [, complete ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $(".alert").delay(1000).addClass("in").fadeOut(4000, function(){
        $(".alert").removeClass("in").show();
    });
  })
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nre6fbm5/74/)